# EIBInterBaseError 'unavailable database' when trying to create a Firebird database in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firebird, dbexpress, interbase

I'm trying to create a Firebird database during runtime. The procedure that I'm using to do this is this one:

```
procedure CreateDatabase(DBName: String);
var
  IBDatabase1: TIBDatabase;
begin
  IBDatabase1 := TIBDatabase.Create(Self);
  try
    IBDatabase1.DatabaseName := ChangeFileExt(DBName, '.fdb');
    IBDatabase1.Params.Add('USER ''SYSDBA''');
    IBDatabase1.Params.Add('PASSWORD ''masterkey''');
    IBDatabase1.Params.Add('PAGE_SIZE 4096');
    IBDatabase1.Params.Add('DEFAULT CHARACTER SET WIN1252');
    IBDatabase1.CreateDatabase;
  finally
    IBDatabase1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I've achieved this without problems in any little project that I create to teste this function. However, if I try to run this code in the same machine, same Delphi, same everything, except that it is a different (and quite big) project, I get the following error on the IBDatabase1.CreateDatabase line:

```
First chance exception at $7579B9BC. Exception class EIBInterBaseError with message 'unavailable database'. Process xxx.exe (4144)
```

Anybody has any clues about this one? Maybe some way to debug this properly?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

It seems to be something in my project file. I've managed to generate a new one and the problem is gone, but I'm afraid of being bitten by this in the future. What could possibilly cause this?

Comment: What changed in your project file? You're sure the project file is the *only* thing you changed?

Comment: Not sure, cause I'm doing things in quite a hurry. But I've created a new project file, added all the files of my project and executed it. The database was created normally. I'm still checking things and I'm gonna put more output soon.

Comment: Your source-control system's "diff" tool should be able to show you what changed.

Comment: It should, if Delphi's IDE wouldn't be a XML where order doesn't matter. The files look similar, but the positions of the field are all messed up. It is really hard to pinpoint the differences. So far, only the project file changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't my project file. It was an old GDS32.dll that was dropped in the same directory as the executable. Removing it solved the issue. Hope this might help someone with the same problem.